# How can I get, use, and remove the first card form the deck(list)?

Tags: c#, oop

I can't believe I can't figure this out.  I have a Blackjack assignment this weekend. I've got a deck of cards.  I have shuffled the deck of cards. Now I want to start building the users hand by dealing him two cards.  I would like to make an addCard method that takes the card at the top of the list and inserts it into the hand.  I think I know how to remove it, but I'm having a hard time just getting it.   I've tried getting it from deck, from Cards and it just doesn't like anything. It tells me cards doesn't exist in the current format.  Thanks!

```
class BlackJackDeck
{
    private const int DECKSIZE = 52;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int cardCount = 0;
    public List<Card> playerHand;
    public List<Card> dealerHand;

    public IList<BlackJackCard> Cards { get; private set; }

    public BlackJackDeck()
    {
        NewDeck();
    }



    private void NewDeck()
    {
        Cards = new List<BlackJackCard>(DECKSIZE);

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 13; j++)
            {
                switch (j)
                {
                    case 8:
                    case 9:
                    case 10:
                    case 11:
                        Cards.Add(new BlackJackCard { Suit = (Suit)i, Face = (CardFace)j, Value = 10 });
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        Cards.Add(new BlackJackCard { Suit = (Suit)i, Face = (CardFace)j, Value = 11 });
                        break;
                    default:
                        Cards.Add(new BlackJackCard { Suit = (Suit)i, Face = (CardFace)j, Value = (j + 2)});
                        break;
                 }
            }
         }
        }
        public object shuffleCards()
        {
            foreach (var Card in Cards)
            {

                Card.ShuffleRank = rnd.Next(100);
                Cards = Cards.OrderBy(x => x.ShuffleRank).ToList();


            }
            return Cards;
        }


        BlackJackDeck deck = new BlackJackDeck();

        public void needShuffle()
        {
            if (Cards.Count == 0)
            {

                deck.shuffleCards();
            }
        }

    }
    public void addCard()
    {

        Card cardToAdd = Cards[0]
    }
```

Comment: You need to clean up the code you provided, but assuming those braces are in the current location, `addCard` is defined outside of BlackJackDeck.

Comment: I see you still went with adding the property for ShuffleRank, that is totally unneeded. What we worked on yesterday was good. Also Shuffle cards doesn't need to return anything. You would use deck.Cards again after doing a shuffle. Even if you did want to return something you would return an IEnumerable<Card> or List<Card> not object.

Comment: Hey, what's up?  Yeah, I tried a bunch of times to shuffle without the shuffleRank and I couldn't get it to work.  I've shuffleCards so it doesn't return anything.  Can't remember what I was thinking on that one.  What does the code look like without the shuffleRank?

Answer (score 0):

Better ask in board and card games community.